# Parentheses in the section numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

To put a ")" in the heading number, I included it on the code below:

```
\titleformat
    {\section} % Section type being modified
    [block] % Section layout type, can be: hang, block, display, runin, leftmargin, rightmargin, drop, wrap, frame
    {\raggedright\LARGE\bfseries} % Text formatting of the whole section, i.e. label and title
    {\thesection} % Section label (e.g. number) and its formatting
    {0pt} % Horizontal space between the section label and title
    {)   } % Code before the section title
    [] % Code after the section title

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{4pt} % Spacing around section titles, the order is: left, before and after
```

It worked as shown in the image below:

[image]

Unfortunately, it mess up with the table of contents:

[image]

Is there another way of inserting ")" on the heading number or to a way to fix the table of contents?

Thanks!

Edit: I am using package titletoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing the arguments to `\titleformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\raggedright\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\thesection)}
  {\fontdimen2\font}% a normal space
  {}

\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}
  {\baselineskip}
  {4pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{List of abbreviations}

\section{Foreword}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using ifthenelse:

```
\titleformat
{\section} % Section type being modified
[block] % Section layout type, can be: hang, block, display, runin, leftmargin, rightmargin, drop, wrap, frame
{\raggedright\LARGE\bfseries} % Text formatting of the whole section, i.e. label and title
{\thesection} % Section label (e.g. number) and its formatting
{0pt} % Horizontal space between the section label and title
{\ifthenelse{\equal{\thesection}{0}}{}{)  }} % Code before the section title
[] % Code after the section title
```

'''